# Multiple Google charts on one web page

Tags: google-visualization

I've 2 google charts on one page and both are displayed correctly. The problem is when I set fontName of both charts to 'Open Sans', only one chart is displayed. If both charts have some other font like 'Arial', then both are displayed. Also, if fontName for one chart is 'Open Sans' and 'Arial' for other, both charts are displayed. Error is only with 'Open Sans' for both charts. I've included Below is my code snippet. Can't get a solution to this. Please help. Thanks in advance..!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function commodityChart(){
  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
          if($data[$i]->SEGMENT == 'COMMODITY'){
          echo "['" . $data[$i]->PARAMETER . "'," . $data[$i]->AMOUNT . "],";
      }
    }

?>
    ]);

     var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '₹', format:'##,##,###.00'} );
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    // Set chart options
    var options = {pieHole: 0.4,
       fontSize: 13,
      fontName: 'Open Sans', 
      is3D : true,
      pieSliceText: 'value',
      sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
     // pieStartAngle: 100,
      slices: {0: {offset: 0.3}},
      //fontName: 'Open Sans',
       legend: {position: 'right', alignment:'end'},
       colors: ['#9bc53d', '#FF9900'],
                   'width':600,
                 //  chartArea:{left:30,top:20,width:'70%',height:'75%'},
                   'height':500};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('gchart_pie_2'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function equityChart(){

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart1);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart1() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn('string', 'type');
    data1.addColumn('number', 'amount');
    //data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});

    data1.addRows([
              <?
        for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
          if($data[$i]->SEGMENT == 'EQUITY'){
          echo "['" . $data[$i]->PARAMETER . "'," . $data[$i]->AMOUNT . "],";
      }
    }
?>
    ]);

     var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({prefix: '₹', format:'##,##,###.00'} );
    formatter.format(data1, 1);

    // Set chart options
    var options1 = {pieHole: 0.4,
     is3D: true,`enter code here`
      legend: {position: 'right', alignment:'end'},
       //fontSize: 13,
       fontName: 'Open Sans',
       forceIFrame: false,
      // pieSliceBorderColor: 'red',
       pieSliceText: 'value',
       //pieSliceTextStyle: {fontName: 'Open Sans', fontSize: 13},
       chartArea:{left:20,top:20,width:'70%',height:'75%'},
      // pieStartAngle: 20,
     // slices: {0: {offset: 0.4}},
       sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
       // colors: ['#5bc0eb','#fde74c', '#9bc53d', '#e55934', '#fa7921'],
        colors: ['#9bc53d','#fde74c', '#e55934', '#5bc0eb', '#FF9900'],
        //tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                   'width':600,
                   'height':500};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('gchart_pie_1'));
    chart1.draw(data1, options1);
  }
}
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try drawings the charts one at a time, that seems to fix the problem...

Here, I use the `ready` event to wait for the first chart to draw, then draw the second.

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  commodityChart();
}

function commodityChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Pepperoni', 33],
    ['Hawaiian', 26],
    ['Mushroom', 22],
    ['Sausage', 10],
    ['Anchovies', 9]
  ]);

  var options = {
    pieHole: 0.4,
    fontSize: 13,
    fontName: 'Open Sans',
    is3D: true,
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
    slices: {
      0: {
        offset: 0.3
      }
    },
    legend: {
      position: 'right',
      alignment:'end'
    },
    colors: [
      '#9bc53d',
      '#FF9900'
    ],
    width: 600,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('gchart_pie_2'));
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', equityChart);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

function equityChart() {
  var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data1.addColumn('string', 'type');
  data1.addColumn('number', 'amount');
  data1.addRows([
    ['Work',     11],
    ['Eat',      2],
    ['Commute',  2],
    ['Watch TV', 2],
    ['Sleep',    7]
  ]);

  var options1 = {
    pieHole: 0.4,
    is3D: true,
    legend: {
      position: 'right',
      alignment: 'end'
    },
    fontName: 'Open Sans',
    forceIFrame: false,
    pieSliceText: 'value',
    chartArea: {
      left: 20,
      top: 20,
      width: '70%',
      height: '75%'
    },
    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
    colors: [
      '#9bc53d',
      '#fde74c',
      '#e55934',
      '#5bc0eb',
      '#FF9900'
    ],
    width: 600,
    height: 500
  };

  var chart1 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('gchart_pie_1'));
  chart1.draw(data1, options1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="gchart_pie_1"></div>
<div id="gchart_pie_2"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, one note: I typically only call `google.load` once, and only set one callback function...